# Как правильно изменить файловую систему?

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, файловая-система, dual-boot

Устанавливаю Ubuntu рядом с Windows 7, причем хочу, чтобы не потерялись данные. Проблема возникает на этапе уменьшения размера диска, чтобы создать раздел для ubuntu. Пробовал изменять файловую систему как во время установки, так и через `GParted`, загрузившись в Ubuntu. Вот текст ошибки:

```
ntfsresize v2015.3.14AR.1 (libntfs-3g)
Device name : /dev/sda4
NTFS volume version: 3.1
Cluster size : 4096 bytes
Current volume size: 104857596416 bytes (104858 MB)
Current device size: 104857600000 bytes (104858 MB)
New volume size : 353306944000 bytes (353307 MB)
ERROR: New size can't be bigger than the device size.
If you want to enlarge NTFS then first enlarge the device size by e.g. fdisk.
```

[Скриншот из windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I0dDT.png)

[Скриншот из linux](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8A73.png)

Как-то странно разделы отображаются в Ubuntu: разделы D, E, L выглядят как один... В разделе L у меня 60 Гб свободно, а я уменьшаю объем на 40.

Всего у меня 6 разделов в Windows: зарезервированный для Bitlocker 1 мб, зарезервированный системой 100 мб, раздел с системой (диск С в wibdows) и 3 пользовательских раздела. В Linux же я вижу только 4. Что я делаю не так и как создать раздел для Linux без потерь данных?

Comment: Не пробовал сначала ужать ФС, а потом создавать? У gparted в старых версиях был такой глюк, что пачкой глючил, а по одиночке задания ном выполнялись.

Comment: наблюдаю в вопросе путаницу в понятиях (внесённую когда-то маркетологами из *ms*): есть блочное устройство («винчестер»), на нём могут располагаться разделы (имеющие начало и конец, не обязательно занимающие всё устройство, и не обязательно вплотную прилегающие друг к другу), на разделе может быть создана файловая система (обычно, но не обязательно, занимающая всё пространство раздела), файловая система может содержать файлы, каталоги и прочие объекты ф.с., которые разбросаны по всему пространству, занимаемому ф.с. // когда они занимают всё пространство, это называют «ф.с. заполнена».

Comment: @alexanderbarakin физический винчестер у меня один. На нем описанные 6 разделов, теперь понятнее?

Comment: @Nik, главное, чтоб вам было понятно, что же на самом деле означает, например, «диск d» в переводе с маркетолочески-майкрософтовского суржика.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin диск d, насколько я понимаю, - это раздел физического винчестера. Ну, к вопросу вообще это косвенное отношение имеет...

Comment: @Nik более точно: это файловая система, созданная на одном из разделов одного из подключенных блочных устройств. терминология становится критически значимой тогда, когда неправильное её использование вносит путаницу и затрудняет восприятие «общей картины». в вопросе я именно это и наблюдаю (начиная со слов «как-то странно диски …»).

Comment: @alexanderbarakin поправил.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй сначала ужать диск и создать новый чистый раздел для Linux из под Win7.
А создавать файловые системы уже можно в процессе установки или через GParted, загрузившись с live_cd

Comment: Я уже пробовал так. Только вот то неназначенное пространство, которое я выделяю в винде не видно в линуксе.

Comment: Может глюк какой-то. Разделы "unknown" должны быть видны. Еще раз: создавая раздел из под Windows, не надо вообще никак форматировать новый раздел. Если там что-то есть - надо нажать "удалить раздел", естесственно при этом в данном разделе не должно быть важной информации. Чтобы было просто пустое неотформатированное пространство. Из GParted оно должно быть видно как "unknown".

Comment: я все понимаю. Я так и делал, чтобы оставалась пустое, неназначенное пространство, однако в GParted его нет. Там как будто все пространство назначенное.